# All fields plus additional ones in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wanting to select all fields plus some additional ones too.  How do I do this?  I have tried the following:

```
SELECT *, TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OURSTART, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS SOM,
TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OUREND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS EOM
FROM OURUSER.THC_MAIN
```

Comment: so what is problem you facing on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the asterisk and you'll be all set:

```
SELECT
  THC_MAIN.*,
  TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OURSTART, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS SOM,
  TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OUREND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS EOM
FROM OURUSER.THC_MAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  THC_MAIN.*, TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OURSTART, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS SOM,
  TO_CHAR(THC_MAIN.OUREND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS EOM
FROM OURUSER.THC_MAIN
```